# how to translate this if statement?into the common form

Tags: c++, if-statement

can someone please translate this if statement into the common form? I cant understand what it means..

```
//str[i++] = (rem > 9) ? (rem - 10) + 'a' : rem + '0';
```

taken from this code:

```
while (num != 0)
    {
        int rem = num % base;
        str[i++] = (rem > 9)? (rem-10) + 'a' : rem + '0';
        num = num/base;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: You will have to provide more context than that. Also which part exactly do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I edited. @RSahu yes I did but it is incorrect. I thought it was if (rem > 9)
   str[i++] = (rem - 10) + 'a';
  else
   str[i++] = rem + '0';

Comment: but it is illogical

Comment: @Cocoboom - What's illogical about it?

Comment: How is your attempt incorrect? Did you get any errors?

Comment: There is no if statement in your code.

Comment: Note that the result of `(rem-10) + 'a'` (with or without the unnecessary parentheses) depends on the current locale. There is no requirement that the values that represent letters be contiguous or increasing. On the other hand, `rem + '0'` is required to work when `rem` has any value from 0 to 9, inclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to translate this if statement?into the common form

The code line with the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

`str[i++] = (rem > 9) ? (rem - 10) + 'a' : rem + '0';`

can also be expressed with the following simple `if-else` statements:

```
if(rem > 9)
   str[i++] = (rem - 10) + 'a' ;
else
   str[i++] = rem + '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it was
>
> ```
> if (rem > 9)
>   str[i++] = (rem - 10) + 'a';
> else
>   str[i++] = rem + '0';`
> ```

That is correct.

> but it is illogical

It does not seem illogical to me.

It seems the user is trying to convert a number to a hexadecimal string.

For numbers 10, ... 15, the user wants to assign the letters `a`, ... `f` to `str[i]`.

For numbers 0, ... 9, the user wants to assign the digits `0`, ... `9` to `str[i]`.

That logic is well captured in that statement.